# php __DIR__ to other location

Tags: php

Say I have `echo realpath( dirname(__DIR__) );` that points me to /usr/location

How can I use the same mechanism to point to /usr/otherplace?

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 2):

The question isn't totally clear, so I am answering it how I took it.

A simple method is to allow the file system to sort it out and just append `/../otherplace`

```
realpath( dirname(__DIR__) ) . '/../otherplace';
```

Otherwise you are going to have to parse the file string, which the simplest method is to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode), manipulate the array (In this case setting the last element to otherplace)  and then use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) to reassemble it.